# The torus is in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{4}$?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Always I belived that the torus is in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, but reading about the clifford Tori I read that the Clifford torus is in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.  I don't understand it. Since in differential Geometry I had learned tha the torus is in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, but now if I consider the tours as $\mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}$, then it is in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. How explain it?

Comment: The torus can be embedded into all sorts of spaces of all different dimensions. What makes a torus *a torus* has nothing to do with the ambient space in which we place it.

Comment: Also, you can consider it as an abstract manifold. Then there is no need for any ambient space at all.

Comment: Topologically they’re the same, i.e., diffeomorphic. But they’re geometrically different. The Clifford torus is flat. The one in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not.

Comment: Thank you all, I understand. I was confused thinking that when I put in the parametrization of the torus $x:u\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{T}^{2}$ has implicit that the it is in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, but it's not like that. Only one question more. we say that the Clifford torus is flat since it is in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, and then $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is in some sense a "plane".?

Comment: Late to the party, but regarding the last comment: There are lots of non-flat tori in four-space, so I would not say, "...the Clifford torus is flat _since_ it is in [four-space]." What's true is, there is no flat torus in three-space, and _some_ flat tori (rectangular ones) can be isometrically embedded in four-space. <> Separately, when we speak of "the torus" it matters how much structure we assume the torus has: _topological_, _smooth_, _conformal_, and _metric_ are common choices.